# How to revert back to normal theme?

Tags: themes

I enabled dark theme in elementary OS 5.1 using this command: "***wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/veyselerden/elementaryos-dark-theme-enabler-script/master/enable-dark-theme.sh && chmod +x enable-dark-theme.sh && ./enable-dark-theme.sh***"
How do I revert back to the normal theme?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The script copied some setting changes into gtk config. So you just need to delete that file.

```
sudo rm -rf ~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini
```

The dock theme however is overridden by the script, so you need to find a suitable theme at gnome-look.org

[Plank themes here[1](https://www.gnome-look.org/browse/cat/273/order/latest/)

Extract the package to `.local/share/plank/themes` (hidden in your home directory)

Open the terminal type;

```
plank --preferences
```

You’ll now be greeted by this menu.

[image]

You can now pick the theme you downloaded.